# How to generate new dataframe from SQL like clause?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this. We will call it df1:

```
  zone          script    datetimecomplete
0   2.0       Consumers 2018-05-03 16:09:48
1   2.0       Inventory 2018-05-03 16:09:48
2   2.0  Orders_Details 2018-05-03 16:09:48
3   3.0       Consumers 2018-05-03 16:09:48
4   3.0       Inventory 2018-05-03 16:09:48
5   3.0  Orders_Details 2018-05-03 16:09:48
6   6.0        Birthday 2018-05-03 16:09:48
```

I have to create another dataframe (df2) based on df1. The requirement is that for each `'zone' and 'script'` columns I need to generate the count of script in the last 24 hours(only need to compare the date not timestamps). Only need to append rows where `datetimecomplete` column is Today minus 1 day.

df2 needs to have 4 columns:

```
[zone, script, datetimecomplete, totalcount]
```

zone - same as df1
script - same as df1
datetimecomplete - current date minus 1 day needs to appended into df2
totalcount - needs to be count of each individual script in the last 24hours from todays date.

Example of df2:

```
 zone          script    datetimecomplete    totalcount
  2.0       Consumers 2018-05-02 16:09:48     2
  2.0       Inventory 2018-05-02 16:09:48     1
  2.0  Orders_Details 2018-05-02 16:09:48     1
  3.0       Consumers 2018-05-02 16:09:48     1
  3.0       Inventory 2018-05-02 16:09:48     1
  3.0  Orders_Details 2018-05-02 16:09:48     4
  6.0        Birthday 2018-05-02 16:09:48     6
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Code so far, gets me the count but not for the last 24hours from df1 nor does it create the `totalcount` column:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['zone', 'script', df1['datetimecomplete'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)])['script'].count()
```

sample SQL query I am trying to accomplish:

```
select df1.zone, df1.script, currentdate - 1 as [datetimecomplete], count(df1.zone) as [TotalCount]

from [df1] as a

where df1.datetimecomplete = currentdate - 1

group by df1.zone, df1.script
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your `df1`, shown in the example enough to produce `df2`? I mean, I do not see 6 counts for `birthday` script.

Comment: @HarvIpan the 6 is not a count but an internal code. I think there is enough to make df2

Comment: I was actually referring to `totalcount` for birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to perform your problem if I understand, you can create a `mask_24h` to select the data from `df1` in the last 24h:

```
h24_ago = (pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta(days=1)).date() # time 24h ago
mask_24h = df1['datetimecomplete'] >= h24_ago
```

Then to create your `df2` you are right to use `groupby` but I would do this way:

```
df2 = df1[mask_24h ].groupby(['zone','script']).\
         count().reset_index().rename(columns = {'datetimecomplete':'totalcount'})
```

here you select the data from `df1` within the last 24h with `df1[mask_date]` then you `groupby()` on `'zone'` and `'script'` and proceed the `count()`. `reset_index()` allows to keep the other columns and `rename()` to rename. Now you are just missing the column `'datetimecomplete'` so do:

```
df2['datetimecomplete'] = h24_ago
```

Hope it works

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response this is what I need. However the date comparison is not working. I am still getting a count of 1 in total count when there are no records less than Today minus 1 day in df1. The count should be zero.  Is there a way to only compare dates and not timestamps?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Not sure I understand, when you say dates you mean the day? so like you want all the script run yesterday, or the script run between now and yesterday at midnight?

Comment: That is correct I mean the day. I the script ran betwee now and yesterday at midnight.

Comment: @RustyShackleford see my EDIT, but I guess you did as you reply since :)